# SVN commit error after deleting files locally

Tags: svn, version-control, netbeans, commit

I have a project that I am building with Netbeans 6.1 and I am using SVN. I deleted some files on the local machine then attempted to commit my changes to th SVN repository. The commit fails with the error message

> Entry for 'C:\path\to\project\myfile' has no URL

Where myfile is the deleted file.

Is there some way to tell SVN that the file was deleted from the project and that it should be deleted from the repository?

Comment: I know this is ancient... but did you delete the file from inside the IDE or from the command-line/file explorer?

Comment: I absolutely cannot remember. Shortly after this I moved on to Mercurial and have never looked back.

Answer (score 116, accepted):

An svn update will bring the file back, fixing your local repo.

You should then be able to do an "svn delete" on the file, which tells your local repo that the file is to be deleted, and also deletes it from the file system.

You should then be able to commit the changes back to the repo.

Answer (score 2):

If you are comitting a folder with the deleted file in it and supposing that you use the latest versions of Tortoise SVN (SVN GUI Client), it recognizes the particular file as missing and tries to delete from the SVN repo.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and the reason was that I deleted the file externaly. If you delete it using NetBeans, then commit work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the project locally, rechecking out from SVN and committing the changes fixed it for me. Make sure to back up your changes before deleting the project.