# How to delete a .git file from svn?

Tags: git, svn

I created an iOS project with git repository option set.Later I had to move to SVN. The .git folder was not deleted when I added it to SVN. Now I deleted the .git folder. BUt when I try to remove it from SVN repository, I get the below error:

**Commit failed (details follow):
Entry for '/Users/user1/Development/Source code/Working Copy/Sample Project/.git' has no URL**

How do I remove the .git folder from repository?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/242376/svn-commit-error-after-deleting-files-locally

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove a file/directory using the `svn` command, *not* manually delete it first.

So revert your working copy first using `svn update` and then use `svn rm .git` to properly remove the .git directory.

Next you can commit your changes.